# Custom Image Button control click handler not firing

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I've got a bit of an issue with creating a new control based on ASP.NET's ImageButton control. Everything works as expected, except for the click handler that is being hooked up in the control's OnInit override. Basically, clicking the custom image button just refreshes the page, never hitting the handler.

Now, I know this is something stupid I've done or just not understood, but I can't for the life of me figure this out. All the articles, questions and forum posts I've found on event handling issues for controls is for child controls, rather than ones that inherit from existing control types and have their own predefined handlers.

The following code is what I've written:

```
public class WebPaymentButton : ImageButton
{
    public string DisabledImageUrl { get; set; }

    public string TermsAcceptClass { get; set; }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptResource(typeof (WebPaymentButton), "PaymentModule.Scripts.WebPaymentButtonScript.js");
    }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        CssClass = "WebPaymentButton";

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TermsAcceptClass))
        {
            Attributes["data-TermsClass"] = TermsAcceptClass;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DisabledImageUrl))
        {
            Attributes["data-DisabledImageUrl"] = ResolveUrl(DisabledImageUrl);
        }


        Click += WebPaymentButton_Click;

        base.OnInit(e);
    }


    private void WebPaymentButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://dummy_payment_page_in_place_of_code", true);
    }
}
```

I've tried hooking the handler up in the OnLoad and also switching it to run after the base.OnInit/OnLoad calls. Nothing has solved the handler issue. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

In case it helps, here is the markup for the button on the page:

```
<pm:WebPaymentButton runat="server" ImageUrl="~/pay-now.png" DisabledImageUrl="~/not-pay-now.png" TermsAcceptClass="TermsCheckbox" ID="MainPayButton" />
```

Comment: So what happens where you change `private void WebPaymentButton_Click` to `protected void WebPaymentButton_Click`?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Trying this suggestion changes nothing. There are no errors or warnings in either case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried overriding the `OnClick` event handler instead of hooking up to a new event handler?

Remove the `Click += WebPaymentButton_Click` line from `OnInit` and remove the `WebPaymentButton_Click` function, then add the following code to your class instead:

```
protected override void OnClick(ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnClick(e);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://dummy_payment_page_in_place_of_code", true);
}
```